# Limit of the stack

Tags: stack

Recently I've tested the limit of a stack on three devices with different OSs (by limit, I mean the maximum number of levels that can the stack have), and I noticed that every time when I hit 2^16 levels it gives me overflow error, and when I put 2^16-1 it works properly.

So my question is - is that true? Does the stack has the maximum limit 2^16-1 by definition or it depends on the OS?

Comment: `here i mean by limit the maximum number of levels that can the stack have` whats a level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is call stack not implemented as a dynamic array in modern OS?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335065/why-is-call-stack-not-implemented-as-a-dynamic-array-in-modern-os)

Comment: How are you testing it?  Are you using a 2-byte (dword) as input?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Such a sharp limit at a fixed number indicates it's a deliberate limitation by your language specific runtime and not by the stack size the OS allocated. For example python seems to enforce a limit of 1000 by default to prevent you from hitting a real stack overflow (recovering from a real stack overflows is hard)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the call stack have a static maximum size?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330626/why-does-the-call-stack-have-a-static-maximum-size)

Comment: @gnat: That question is a bit far afield.

Answer (score 21):

It is strongly operating system specific (& computer specific) and on some OSes you have some ways to configure (and even increase) the limit. It is even compiler specific (or your-programming-language-implementation specific), since some compilers (including recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for some *limited* kind of C code) are able to optimize *some* [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

<sup>(some programming language specifications *require* tail call optimizations, e.g. [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/))</sup>

I'm not sure your question makes sense (and certainly not your 2<sup>16</sup> limit). On my Linux desktop (Debian/Sid/x86-64, Linux 4.9 kernel, 32Gb RAM, Intel i5-4690S), I might have a [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of up to 8 megabytes (and I could increase that limit, if I really wanted to).

[Multi-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) and [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) are making your question *much more complex*. See e.g. [pthread_attr_setstack(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstack.3.html). Read also about [split stacks](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks) (often used by [Go](http://go-lang.org/) implementations) and about [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/339937/40065) answer.

For what it is worth, I just tried the following C99 (and also C11) code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void recfun(int x, int d) {
  printf("start recfun x=%d d=%d\n", x, d);
  fflush(NULL);
  if (d>0)
    recfun(x+1, d-1);
  printf("end recfun x=%d d=%d\n", x, d);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  int md = argc>1?atoi(argv[1]):10000;
  printf ("start md=%d\n", md);
  recfun(0, md);
  printf("end md=%d clock=%ld µs\n", md, clock());
}    
// eof recur.c
```

and I was able to run that `recur` program (compiled with GCC 6 as `gcc -Wall -O recur.c -o recur`) as `recur 161000`  (so much above your 2<sup>16</sup> limit). With `recur 256000` it also worked. With `recur 456000` it crashed (with a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) for level `x=272057`). I don't have the patience for other tests. Try that on your computer. Don't forget to ask for optimizations.

A rule of thumb (for desktops, laptops, tablets) might be to keep your call stack below one megabyte.

By passing also `-fstack-usage` [to](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options) `gcc` I'm getting the following `recur.su` file (numbers are in bytes, consistent with my 8Mb stack limit intuition; don't forget the `main` call frame, and more importantly the initial stack layout, installed by the kernel when doing [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)..., for [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)):

```
 recur.c:5:10:recfun    32  static
 recur.c:13:9:main  16  static
```

PS. My Arduino has a [Atmega328](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATmega328) with only 2Kbytes of RAM, so certainly cannot recur that much. I guess only a few hundreds stack frames are at most practically possible on Arduinos.

Answer (score 4):

Stack size for the main thread of a process Windows is set by the linker.  The default is 1MB but can be adjusted with the /STACK switch.  Threads created later can use the dwStackSize parameter of the CreateThread function.

So.. if you're testing various Windows OS's, they've all had the same default stack size since at least NT4.0.